# How to change month name to english?

Tags: language-support, localization, system-language

My calender screenshot :

[image]

How I can change to English day names or other things?

Comment: That doesn't look like a terminal. Can you better explain what you mean?

Comment: @Seth sorry, I fixed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it.

## First: All setting

[image]

## Next: Language Support

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to open a terminal window, open ~/.profile for editing, add the line

```
export LC_TIME=$LANG
```

and relogin. However, that will change the time and date format in several places to English.

Comment: sorry this change just terminal date to english, in all of my ubuntu sections I see this. How to fix for all sections?

Comment: @chalist: It would have changed the weekday and month names in the clock/calendar application as well. But maybe you want American regional formats all over, and then your own answer is the way to go. I'm glad you solved it. :)